# JAXWS - SOAP WebService - Null object on client despite the XML response from WebService

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, jaxb2

I need your help.
 The version used is JAX-WS RI 2.2.6b21 / SOAP 1.2

I am developing a WS client to connect a WebService server made by a vendor.
 I am able to send the next XML request :

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:executeAbout xmlns:ns2="http://vendor.com/">
            <About/>
        </ns2:executeAbout>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

and below the XML response form WebService server :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://vendor.com/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <executeAboutResponse xmlns="">
            <AboutResponse success="true">
            </AboutResponse>
        </executeAboutResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

the `AboutResponseType`  class :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AboutResponseType", propOrder = {
    "result",
    "messages"
})
public class AboutResponseType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Result")
    protected AboutResultType result;
    @XmlElement(name = "Messages")
    protected MessagesType messages;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "success")
    protected Boolean success;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the result property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link AboutResultType }
     *     
     */
    public AboutResultType getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the result property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link AboutResultType }
     *     
     */
    public void setResult(AboutResultType value) {
        this.result = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the messages property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link MessagesType }
     *     
     */
    public MessagesType getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the messages property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link MessagesType }
     *     
     */
    public void setMessages(MessagesType value) {
        this.messages = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the success property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public Boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the success property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public void setSuccess(Boolean value) {
        this.success = value;
    }

}
```

But unfortunatly, the JAVA object response is null and no java exception is raised :

```
AboutType aboutType = new AboutType();
AboutResponseType aboutResponse = myProxy.executeAbout(aboutType);
 assertNotNull(aboutResponse);
```

What I understood by searching on internet, it's a namespace issue in the reponse.
 But where is the issue and how to fix it ?

Thanks a lot for your help, I'm out of idea.

Comment: Please add code of the class AboutResponseType so that we know how you have mapped the response

Comment: Hello,I am sorry, I am just seeing your request about adding code.

Comment: I will do it on Monday Regards,